# Exponential Decay with a Factory Machine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

The value V of a factory machine depreciated with time t years such that dV/dt=-kV, for some constant k>0.

(i) Show that V=V_0 e^(-kt) satisfies the given differential equation.

(ii) The initial value of a particular item of machinery is $15000. Explain why V_0=15000.

(iii) In the first year the machine depreciates in value by 30%. Find the value of the constant k.

(iv) The company that bought the machine writes off any machine when it has depreciated to 5% of its initial value. How many years does this take? Round your answer to the nearest whole year.

I am not good with starting growth and decay questions. Im just trying to do this problem. Any solutions or starting points to quickly do this with working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(i) $\frac{dv}{dt} = -kV$

Separate variables

$\frac{dV}{V} = -k\cdot dt$

$\ln V = -kt + C$

$V  = e^C\cdot e^{-kt}$

When $t = 0$ then....

$V_0 = e^C$

So $V = V_0\cdot e^{-kt}$

(ii) $V_0$ is the value when $t = 0$ which is $\$15 000$ the initial value .

(iii) When $t = 1$ then....

$10500  = 15000\cdot e^{-k}$

$\frac{10500}{15000}  = e^{-k}$

$\ln(0.7) = -k$

$k = 0.356675$

(iv)  $750 = 15000e^{-0.356675t}$

$.05 = e^{-0.356675t}$

$\ln(.05) = -0.356675t$

$t = \frac{-2.995732}{-0.356675}$

$t = 8$ years